# sharing iAd banner across different views in storyboard?

Tags: storyboard, view, iad

I'm having a hard time to figure out how the whole iAd implementation works!
after serching in the forum and trying a lot of different methods - i still havent found a solution for my problem!
I have made an application with a navigation controller and a lot of view controllers.
Im using this code to show the ad in my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>


@end
```

im my ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


@end
```

Then I simply drag the iAd banner from storyboard into my ViewController and set its alpha to 0.
it actually works - so the banner shows up when there is a connection and dissapear when there is no connection.
the problem is that I get this Warning: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.
I know already why this happens, thanks to you guys...but I have no clue how to fix this!
It wold be great if someone could please help me with this, Im trying it for days now!
I have to say that i've just started with xcode so it's kind of hard for me.

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please, don't forget to select an answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I can not tell you about the error message that you get. But this is what works for me:

ViewController.m:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;
```

add this line to the view controller and connect the outlet to the iAd object on the storyboard. Also set the iAd delegate to the ViewController. Then add these two methods to your view controller:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [_adView setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [_adView setHidden:YES];
}
```

That's it, now you should see the iAd test ad in the simulator and no error messages are shown for me.